# Can I Use Traefik with Azure frontdoor private link?

Tags: traefik, traefik-ingress, azure-front-door

I am using traefik with ingress in my AKS application which is in Azure. right now, the domain resolves to ingress LB public IP and traefik routes it to right service. I want to add an Azure Front door(AFD) in between and send the requests between AFD and my service through a private link. I can see it is supported in AFD and Nginx, however could not figure out how to achieve it with traefik. Can someone please help me with how to achieve it?

Comment: I'm not sure if private link is supported for traefik.  How do you have it set up?  Origin support for private link includes internal load balancers or 
 services that expose internal load balancers like AKS:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/private-link#limitations

Comment: Could you provide more details on the current configuration?  Is traefik running on a VM?

Comment: @Narthring, Thanks for the response. I had gone through the link and what my understandingis even if underlying AKS supports PLS, traefik may/may not be implementing it. I saw examples where ngnx is using PLS, tried to expose an internal load balancer the same way and it is showing connected from PLS but is not working when accessed.

Comment: Traefik will be running on a Node in a cluster. We already have connection available to the services in Cluster through public IP.

Comment: It sounds like this should be possible then.  It may be a configuration issue in Kubernetes, since you have AFD and an origin using private link to AKS.  Are you able to hit the Traefik node from a browser directly, without using Front Door?  Any errors you're able to show might help someone who knows more about the private link/AKS side than I do.